# props.logout is not a function at handleLogout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication

I tried doing a logout function in react for a web app.but getting the following error when i click on logout button :

> props.logout is not a function
> at handleLogout

Here is the code

```
//mainpage.js

  const handleLogout = async () => {
    const logOutSuccess = props.logout();

    if (logOutSuccess) {
      navigate("/");
    } else {
      console.log("Sign out failed");
    }
  };


//app.js


let logoutHandler = () => {
    const auth = getAuth(app);
    return signOut(auth)
      .then(() => {
        console.log("User signed out successfully");
        return true; // return true if logout is successful
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        console.log(errorMessage);
        return false; // return false if logout fails
      });
  };
 return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Firstpage />} />

        <Route path="/LogIn" element={<SignIn login={loginHandler} />} />
        <Route
          path="/SignUp"
          element={
            <SignUp
              message={errorMessage}
              register={registrationHandler}
              errorMessage={errorMessage}
            />
          }
        />
        <Route path="/mainpage" element={<Mainpage />} />
        {/*  <Route path="/workputpage" element={<Workoutpage />} />*/}
        <Route path="/" element={<Mainpage logout={logoutHandler} />} />
      </Routes>
</div
```

what changes should be done to correct it? Or maybe some alternative this this

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet for the main page is not completely shown but in my opinion, you have not passed on the props keyword to the mainpage.js component in which you are calling the handleLogout.